# Expand an HTML string to have named character entities

Tags: .net, html-encode, named-entity-recognition

Is there a way in the .NET class library to encode a string so that any character for which a named entity exists is replaced to use this named entity? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode doesn't appear to help:

```
// Result is "$", would like "&euro;" instead
var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("€");
```

Comment: May I ask why you need this? If properly encoded, there aren't many reasons to use named entities any more these days

Comment: @Pekka makes it more readable I guess?

Comment: @Hemal how is, say, `&hellip;` more readable than `…`?

Comment: @Pekka I don't know, but `&euro` seems quite readable

Comment: @Hemal Pandya, more readable to whom? The aliens? Definitely `€` is more readable to humans than `&euro;`.

Comment: @Pekka For some reason people find them useful, because HTML 5 added a bunch of them. The only advantage I see is that they're easier to input if the character is not available in the keyboard.

Comment: You are probably right...OP says <"$", would like "&euro;">...I was going entirely by that

Comment: @Artefacto *that* is a fair point - but they probably should be decoded back into their character before storing in the database in most cases

Comment: Fair point, but there is a reason why we need this: We have a component that produces HTML content for a whole lot of third-party web applications that include it in their HTML output. Some of these web applications don't properly specify character encoding. In particular we have seen a problem with the euro symbol, and replacing it with its named entity solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to get your hands dirty and just grab the canonical list of named entities from the specification and then create a loop that, for every named entity, simply replaces every occurrence of that character with the corresponding entity reference.